# How can I use make a custom bullet in the defaut Beamer LaTeX template?

Tags: beamer

I want to make a star bullet, but there is none defined for the default template. How can I use a star as a custom bullet style?

```
%...
%\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{EB Garamond}
%...

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{I want a star}
\framesubtitle{\ldots}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
        \item C
        \setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
        \item D
        \setbeamertemplate{items}[ball]
        \item E
        \item F
        \item I want to make my own custom bullet, a \FiveStar!
        \setbeamertemplate{items}[star]
        \item But how do I do it? \Frowny
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

[image: rendered TeX]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change a beamer item symbol there are two possibilities:

The first one changes the symbol locally (only for one item) by using the optional argument of `\item`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
        \item[{$\star$}] C
        \item D
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second one changes it globally (for all following items) by using the `\setbeamertamplate` commad:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
        \setbeamertemplate{items}{$\star$}
        \item C
        \item D
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some additional notes regarding the second example:

The general ccommand for switching up the `item` symbol is `\setbeamertemplate{items}[<symbol>]` with `<symbol>` being one of the predefined symbols `triangle`, `circle`, `square` or `ball`. If you want to define a different symbol yourself, you will have to use `\setbeamertemplate{items}{<symbol>}` with the code for the new symbol being enclosed in `{}`.

Please be aware, that with the shown code, both `itemize` end `enumerate` items are affected. If you only want to influence the symbols of `itemize` items, use `\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{$\star$}` instead.

The code influences the symbol of all  nested `itemize` levels. If you want a different symbol for the second level, you can use `\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitems}{<symbol>}` (`\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitems}{<symbol>}` for third level items) and replace `<symbol>`  by the appropriate command for the symbol you want.