# enumitem: other label style

Tags: beamer, enumitem

I am creating a presentation using beamer. Maybe this is a stupid question, but I haven't found something similar on the web: using the packages "enumitem", how can I see different label style, creating an itemize, with the command "setlist[itemize] ..."? In this example that I have created below, the label style is "\textbullet". Where can I find other styles?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}

\usepackage{enumitem}   
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
             leftmargin=*,
             label=\textbullet,
             after =\vspace{-\baselineskip},
             before=\vspace{-\baselineskip} 
             }
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use pretty much whatever LaTeX symbol you like. See http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf for a comprehensive list and just use that instead of `\textbullet` (make sure you import any necessary packages)

Comment: `beamer` offers its own mechanism for `enumerate` lists. Using the `enumitem` package in combination with the `beamer` class is therefore not recommended. `beamer` offers some predefined symbols (`triangle`, `square`, `ball` and `circle`) but you can of course also use a different symbol of your own choice. For an example, you may want to take a look at [my previous answer to a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432377/134144).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. How can I find a way to set a colour for the bullet?

Comment: To set color for itemize bullets, you can set the foreground color `fg` of beamer color template `itemize items`, for example `\setbeamercolor{itemize items}{fg=orange}`.